# writing a SQL statement to display course numbers by an individual

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display course number of class by an individual teacher. The course and teacher's id info is on one table and the teacher's id info and name info is on another table. I can get the correct answer for each statement when entered individually but not when combined. so if I have:

```
select course_no, instructor_id from class;
```

this gives me the course number and instructor's id
then if i do

```
select first_name
     , last_name
     , instructor_id 
  from instructor 
 where First_name = 'specific first_name' 
   and 'specific last_name'
```

this gives me the instructors id, first & last name but when i join these two i get an error. what I'm i missing

Comment: If you could share what error you are receiving and the actual SQL you are attempting, it would go a long way in helping us provide assistance.

Comment: `and 'specific last_name'` always evaluates as true. It's like saying `WHERE 1=1`